# Jupyter notebook fails to connect to kernel due to module name conflict

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I had the following folder structure for a python ML project:

```
├── root
   ├── code
   │   ├── foo.py
   │   └── bar.py
   ├── notebook.ipynb
   ├── foo
   └── bar
```

After writing the two .py files in the `code` folder, I tried to run the two files but had some errors similar to this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.foo'; 'code' is not a package
```

This was caused by imports along the lines of this:

```
from code.foo import x
```

I tried searching for a solution and found out that adding an empty `__init.py__` file would help "having python know my folder was a module" (sorry for the bland description, I can't remember the technicalities). In fact, I had no such errors since. New hierarchy looks like this:

```
├── root
   ├── code
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── foo.py
   │   └── bar.py
   ├── notebook.ipynb
   ├── foo
   └── bar
```

Unfortunately, as I tried opening `notebook.ipynb` with Jupyter Notebook, this failed to connect to the kernel, showing this error in the command prompt:

```
i.e.: the module "code" could not be imported because it is shadowed by:
...\root\code\__init__.py
Please rename this file/folder so that the original module from the standard library can be imported.
```

I could delete/rename the `__init.py__` file everytime I need to use the notebook, but that's not very efficient in terms of workflow. Is there any solution to this conflict? As I stated I have no necessity of keeping the `__init.py__` file, if that information helps.

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is already a package named code in python. So your new package is shadowing the original code package.
Change the name to myPackage for example and it should be fine.

The **init**.py files are mandatory for python to identify the folder as a package, you need to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

To use this package you can use
**import code**

and while using you can write code.x

else you can use
from foo import *
or
**import foo** will work also

Comment: This solution produces this error:
`AttributeError: module 'code' has no attribute 'foo'`